# Set values ​back to start

Tags: java, android, android-studio, arraylist

If I click the button `CHECKOUT` a pop up shows up. In this pop up, you have the chance to abort the transaction. So if you abort the transaction all the values for the Items (French fires, Water, Burger) should be 0 again as seen in the picture below. Right now when i abort the transaction the values stay the way i configured them before. Can you help me with that?

[image]

**OrderActivity.java**

```
package com.nfc.netvision;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Locale;

import static android.widget.Toast.*;

public class OrderActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OrderAdapter.TotalListener {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    ArrayList<ModelOrder> orderArrayList;
    TextView textView_order_price;
    TextView textView_order_count;
    Dialog epicDialog;
    Button btnCheckout;
    Button btnAbort;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_order);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_order_scroll);
        textView_order_price = findViewById(R.id.textView_order_price);
        textView_order_count = findViewById(R.id.textView_order_count);
        btnCheckout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCheckout);


        orderArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        orderArrayList.add(new ModelOrder(R.drawable.coke, "Coka Cola", "Eine Cola hält dich wach und schmeckt dazu.", "3",0));
        orderArrayList.add(new ModelOrder(R.drawable.fastfood, "Pommes", "Fritten für die Titten.", "5",0));
        orderArrayList.add(new ModelOrder(R.drawable.water, "Wasser", "Still und sanft, so mag ich es.", "5",0));
        orderArrayList.add(new ModelOrder(R.drawable.burger, "Burger", "Ach mir fällt nichts ein.", "10",0));

        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager recLiLayoutManager = layoutManager;

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(recLiLayoutManager);

        OrderAdapter adapter = new OrderAdapter(this, orderArrayList, this);

        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        epicDialog = new Dialog(this);

        btnCheckout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showWaitingPopUp();


            }
        });



    }

    private void showWaitingPopUp() {
        epicDialog.setContentView(R.layout.order_popup_waiting);
        epicDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        btnAbort = (Button) epicDialog.findViewById(R.id.btnAbort);
        btnAbort.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               epicDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        epicDialog.show();
    }


    @Override
    public void onTotalChanged(String result) {
        NumberFormat n = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.GERMANY);
        textView_order_price.setText( n.format(Integer.parseInt(result)));
    }

    @Override
    public void onCountChanged(String result) {
        textView_order_count.setText(result);

    }
}
```

**OrderAdapter.java**

```
package com.nfc.netvision;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;


import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Locale;


public class OrderAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<OrderAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private int totalAmount;
    private int totalItems;
    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<ModelOrder> nList;

    private TotalListener listener;

    interface TotalListener{
        void onTotalChanged(String result);
        void onCountChanged(String result);

    }
    OrderAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ModelOrder> list, TotalListener listener) {
        mContext = context;
        nList = list;
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_order_items, parent, false);

        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);

        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        final ModelOrder orderItem = nList.get(position);
        ImageView image = holder.item_image;
        final TextView name, place, price;
        name = holder.item_name;
        place = holder.item_place;
        price = holder.item_price;

        image.setImageResource(orderItem.getImage());

        name.setText(orderItem.getName());
        place.setText(orderItem.getPlace());
        price.setText(orderItem.getPrice());


        holder.order_item_minus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(orderItem.getCounter() > 0) {
                    orderItem.setCounter(orderItem.getCounter()-1);
                    holder.order_item_count.setText("" + orderItem.getCounter());
                    calculatePrice(Integer.parseInt((String) price.getText()), false);
                    countItems(orderItem.getCounter(), false);

                }

            }
        });

        holder.order_item_plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(orderItem.getCounter() < 9) {
                    orderItem.setCounter(orderItem.getCounter() + 1);
                    holder.order_item_count.setText("" + orderItem.getCounter());
                    calculatePrice(Integer.parseInt((String) price.getText()), true);
                    countItems(orderItem.getCounter(), true);
                }
            }
        });




    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return nList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ImageView item_image;
        TextView item_name, item_place, item_price,order_item_minus,order_item_count, order_item_plus;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {

            super(itemView);
            item_image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.order_item_image);
            item_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.order_item_name);
            item_place = itemView.findViewById(R.id.order_item_place);
            item_price = itemView.findViewById(R.id.order_item_price);
            order_item_minus = itemView.findViewById(R.id.order_item_minus);
            order_item_plus = itemView.findViewById(R.id.order_item_plus);
            order_item_count = itemView.findViewById(R.id.order_item_count);
        }
    }

    private void calculatePrice(int pPrice, boolean pUpDown) {
        if(pUpDown) {
            totalAmount = totalAmount + pPrice;
        }
        else {
            totalAmount = totalAmount - pPrice;
        }

        listener.onTotalChanged(totalAmount+ "");
    }

    private void countItems(int pCounter, boolean pUpDown){
        if (pUpDown){
            totalItems = totalItems + 1;
        }
        else{
            totalItems = totalItems - 1;
        }
        listener.onCountChanged(totalItems+ "");

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They stay the way there were because inside your abort button's `onClick` you just dismiss the dialog and do not change the list values.

I suggest iterating through the list and setting all counters to 0.

Also, don't forget to notify your `RecyclerView` that you modified something, in this case you reset all counters to 0. Otherwise, you won't see the changes in your app.

```
private void showWaitingPopUp() {
    epicDialog.setContentView(R.layout.order_popup_waiting);
    epicDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    btnAbort = epicDialog.findViewById(R.id.btnAbort);
    btnAbort.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // Set all orders count to 0
            for (ModelOrder modelOrder: orderArrayList) {
                modelOrder.setCounter(0);
            }
            // Notify RecyclerView about the changes
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            epicDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    epicDialog.show();
}
```

I noticed you didn't have the adapter as a global variable so declare it as such:

```
public class OrderActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OrderAdapter.TotalListener {

    // other variables

    // Change adapter variable to global
    OrderAdapter adapter;

    // ...
```

---

*Side notes:* I also noticed that you passed your activity twice inside your `OrderAdapter` constructor.

```
OrderAdapter adapter = new OrderAdapter(this, orderArrayList, this);
```

You can simply just do:

```
OrderAdapter adapter = new OrderAdapter(this, orderArrayList);
```

Then inside your constructor:

```
OrderAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ModelOrder> list) {
    mContext = context;
    nList = list;

    // You can simply cast the context to the listener
    listener = (TotalListener) context;
}
```

---

Hope my answer helps, happy coding!

---

Edit: I moved my answers to OP's other questions in the chat.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! :) I'm sorry I am a beginner. Unfortunately the layout is not updating (the TextViews). For example 3 x french fries is shown, but it should only show 0 french fries.

Comment: You forgot to set the _holder.order_item_count.setText_ inside your _onBindViewHolder_.

Comment: `onBindViewHolder` is in the class `OrderAdapter.java`. Should I create the same method in the class `OrderActivity.java` ? Or how could I call the method in the  class `OrderAdapter.java`?

Comment: I edited my answer, check below. What I mean is that in code block where you set the text of your items, do also the same to _order item count_.

Comment: Ahhh!! Thank you agian for your help! I'm sorry for my question, but is there also an option to inform this `textView_order_price.setText( n.format(Integer.parseInt(result)));` and the `textView_order_count.setText(result);` that they should be 0 ? In the class  `OrderAdapter.java`  `listener.onCountChanged(totalItems+ "");` ?

Comment: The way you can achieve that is to create your own notify method inside your adapter in which you can call your listener's methods. Also, I edited my answer again, please check it out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213187/discussion-between--and-marcel-david1).